# Kinect laser problems

Tags: turtlebot, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
process[kinect_laser_narrow-6]: started with pid [11613]
[ INFO] [1345651995.309589141]: [/openni_launch] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1345651995.310258410]: [/openni_launch] 1. device on bus 008:16 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00367A04475111A'
[ WARN] [1345651995.313676130]: [/openni_launch] device_id is not set! Using first device.
nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo, boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[FATAL] [1345651995.760413081]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1345651995.760845247]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1345651995.760931777]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1345651995.762017568]: Service call failed!
[openni_manager-2] process has died [pid 11396, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=openni_manager __log:=/home/hyness/.ros/log/554f5f92-eae6-11e1-bc87-94dbc99cb3ba/openni_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/hyness/.ros/log/554f5f92-eae6-11e1-bc87-94dbc99cb3ba/openni_manager-2*.log
respawning...
```

When I try to run the follower program on my turtlebot, everything goes fine, until it hits the section above; then it freaks out and restarts the program again, until it runs into that section again. What does this mean? How do I fix it? Thanks!!!

---

Also, when I run kinect bringup, then start rviz, I can view through the camera on the kinect, but the point cloud and laser scan do not work. Not sure if that helps but...?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42046/kinect-laser-problems/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to what I learned yesterday, this failure is not ROS related. Lots of people are experiencing the same problem and there is a workaround.

The issue is discussed [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise-1204/) in detail.

You may also want to check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/37231/fuerte-ubuntu-1204-kinect-errors/)

About the rviz issue, more explanation (preferably a screenshot) may be needed. Do you echo the related topics and not see any output?

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0